# C++ Class of array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, c++17

I am learning C++ and for that, I try to do a simple game project (having the same rows as columns and randomly distributed numbers from 0-blank to rows*rows-1. Target is for player to change numbers to be in numeric order by rows). Then 0-blank can be switched with any neighborhood horizontally or vertically)  I code it through procedural code and it works fine. Now I am trying to redo it using object-oriented programming and classes.

For that reason I have 2 classes:
Number - stores 2 integers with position x and y
Deck - stores array of Numbers, practically s index of an array is the number itself and Number object just store position.

Deck deck (rows) creates sorted numbers with position and is checked by std::cout.
Now I am trying to implement the shuffle function which will take randomly 2 Numbers and switch their positions (m_posX and m_posY) however trying the same principle to get m_posX is not correct and gives different large numbers compared to the creation of the position.
getNumber just does not work as I intended.
Practically I need to return m_posX and m_posY from exact Number object in array of m_game deck.

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong is welcome.

I have this code:

**Number.h**

```
    #ifndef NUMBER_H
    #define NUMBER_H
    #include <array>
    
    class Number
    {
      public:
    //    Number(int x, int y, int d);
        setPosition (int x, int y);
        setPosition (std::array <int,2> &xy );            // std::array [2]
        setDigits (int d);
        switchPosition (Number &c1, Number &c2);
        std::array<int,2> getPosition ();                 // std::array [2]
        int getPositionX ();
        int getPositionY ();
        int getDigits();                                  // int
    
    
      protected:
        int m_posX;
        int m_posY;
        int m_digits;
    };
    
    #endif // NUMBER_H
```

**Number.cpp**

```
    Number::setPosition (int x, int y)
    {
      m_posX = x;
      m_posY = y;
    }
    
    Number::setPosition (std::array <int,2> &xy )
    {
      m_posX = xy [0];
      m_posY = xy [1];
    }
    
    Number::setDigits (int d)
    {
      m_digits=d;
    }
    
    Number::switchPosition (Number &c1, Number &c2)
    {
      int tempX {c1.m_posX};
      int tempY {c1.m_posY};
      c1.setPosition (c2.m_posX, c2.m_posY);
      c2.setPosition (tempX, tempY);
    }
    
    std::array<int,2> Number::getPosition ()
    {
      static std::array <int,2> position;
      position [0] = m_posX;
      position [1] = m_posY;
      return position;
    }
    
    int Number::getDigits ()
    {
      return m_digits;
    }
    
    int Number::getPositionX ()
    {
      return m_posX;
    }
    int Number::getPositionY ()
    {
      return m_posY;
    }
```

**deck.h**

```
    #ifndef DECK_H
    #define DECK_H
    #include "number.h"
    
    class Deck
    {
      public:
        Deck(int rows=3);
        shuffleDeck (int rows);
        Number & getNumber (int elementNumber);
    
      protected:
        std::array <Number,100> m_game;
    };
    
    #endif // DECK_H
```

**deck.cpp**

```
    #include "deck.h"
    #include "number.h"
    #include "rnd.h"
    #include <iostream>
    
    
    Deck::Deck(int rows)
    {
      std::array <Number,100> m_game;
      for (int j {0}; j < (rows); ++j)
      {
        for (int i {0}; i < (rows); ++i)
        {
          m_game[i+j*rows].setPosition (i,j);
          std::cout << "Number: " << (i+j*rows) << '\t' << "Coordinates: " << '\t' << m_game[i+j*rows].getPosition()[0] <<"," << m_game[i+j*rows].getPosition()[1] << '\n' ;
        };
      };
    
    std::cout << "fc Deck::Deck (int rows) Number10 posX: "<< m_game[10].getPosition()[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << "fc Deck::Deck (int rows) Number10 posY: "<< m_game[10].getPosition()[1] << '\n';
    }
    
    Number & Deck::getNumber (int elementNumber)
    {
      std::cout << "fc Deck::getNumber() Number " << elementNumber << " getPosition X,Y: " << m_game[elementNumber].getPositionX() << "," << m_game[elementNumber].getPositionY() << '\n' ;
      return m_game[elementNumber];
    }
```

**game.cpp  running code**

```
    #include "game.h"
    #include "gmath.h"
    #include "constant.h"
    #include "graphics.h"
    #include "number.h"
    #include "deck.h"
    #include <iostream>
    
    
    int game (int rows)
    {
      int steps = 0;
      Graphics piece {};
      Deck deck(rows);
      Number temp = deck.getNumber(10);
      int tempI = temp.getPosition()[10];
//   
//    THIS DOES NOT WORK GETTING printed large number as 28573728
//    [10] has m_posX set to 2 and m_posY set to 2 by Deck deck (rows);
//
    
      std::cout << "CHECK game.h Number10 positionX: "<< tempI << '\n';
    
      return steps; // for future counting score
    }
```

Comment: you face run-time or compile-time errors?

Comment: No error. Just after function Deck deck (rows); function to get variables m_posX and m_posY using: Number temp = deck.getNumber(10);
  int tempI = temp.getPosition()[0];

  std::cout << "CHECK game.h Number10 positionX: "<< tempI << '\n'; does not work and gets large number.

Comment: This is whole code. "graphics.h", "gmath.h" is prepared but so far not used, "constant.h" is prepared but not used for now. Main function has so far implemented only one call: game(4) to initialize game itself with 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try return by value and not by reference here:

```
Number & Deck::getNumber (int elementNumber)
{
  std::cout << "fc Deck::getNumber() Number " << elementNumber << " getPosition X,Y: " << m_game[elementNumber].getPositionX() << "," << m_game[elementNumber].getPositionY() << '\n' ;
  return m_game[elementNumber];
}
```

like this:

```
Number Deck::getNumber (int elementNumber)
{
  std::cout << "fc Deck::getNumber() Number " << elementNumber << " getPosition X,Y: " << m_game[elementNumber].getPositionX() << "," << m_game[elementNumber].getPositionY() << '\n' ;
  return m_game[elementNumber];
}
```

and of course do not forget to change the declaration:

```
Number getNumber (int elementNumber);
```

Comment: I have tried this but it does not work. Still getting large number as 28573728 and 0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very obvious.

In function `game` you are writing `int tempI = temp.getPosition()[10];`.

The function `getPosition()` returns a `std::array<int, 2>`. So, an array having 2 elements. One for x and one for y position. But with `[10]` your are trying to access the element number 10 from your array (which has only 2 elements). This is an out of bounds error. So, It will read some random nonesense value and show that. This is undefined behaviour.

I am not sure, which compiler you have, but in debug mode, it should throw an exception and inform you about the problem.

Correct it to

```
int tempx = temp.getPosition()[0];
int temp< = temp.getPosition()[1];
```

---

You anyway need to enable **ALL** compiler warnings. It did it and got dozens of messages.

You define many functions without return type. You must use `void` for this, e.g. function `setPosition(int x, int y);` must be defined as `void setPosition(int x, int y);`. And so on.

Also in constructor of `Deck` you are redefining and with that overwriting the already defined array `std::array <Number, 100> m_game;` in class deck. Delete the line in the constructor.

You may also consider to replace the `std::array <int, 2>& xy` by a `std::pair` or a simple `struct` like:

```
struct Position{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

That would be more intuitive . . .

Comment: Thanks, all your advice is good ones and it works now. Relating replacement of std::array <int,2> with std::pair or struct, what is the best one? I use std::pair, it is simpler than array but relating to struct, is it not more complicated for temporary variables storage?